# R to get moving averages

Tags: r

Have made some progress on this exercise but getting an argument is not numeric or logical:

Here is the code:

```
      #import libraries
      library(quantmod)
      library(BatchGetSymbols)
      library(TTR)
      library(shiny)
      library(lubridate)
      library(neuralnet) # Neural net library

      #import the first 20 stocks
      df_SP500 <- GetSP500Stocks()

      tickers <- head(df_SP500$Tickers,20)

      #set date
      my_date <- Sys.Date()
      first.date <- my_date %m-% years(20)
      last.date <- Sys.Date()

      #pull data from tickers
      stockValues <- list()

      for (i in 1:length(tickers)){
        stockValues[[i]] <- getSymbols(tickers[i],auto.assign = FALSE, from = first.date)
      }

      #set up list for values
      df_Svalues <- list()
      for (i in 1:length(tickers)){
      # df_Svalues[[i]] <- stockValues[[i]][,paste0(tickers[i], ".Adjusted")]
        df_Svalues[[i]] <- stockValues[[i]][,6]
        df_Svalues[[i]]$mav10 <- 0
        df_Svalues[[i]]$mav50 <- 0
        df_Svalues[[i]]$mav200 <- 0
      }
      head(df_Svalues[[1]])

      for (i in 1:length(tickers)){
        # Moving Average - 10
        for (j in 11:nrow(df_Svalues[[i]])){
          df_Svalues[[i]]$mav10[j] <- mean(df_Svalues[[i]]$adjusted[(j-10):(j-1)])
        }
        # Moving Average - 50
        for (j in 51: nrow(df_Svalues[[i]])) {
          df_Svalues[[i]]$mav50[j] <- mean(df_Svalues[[i]]$adjusted[(j-50):(j-1)])
        }
        # Moving Average - 200
        for (j in 201:nrow(df_Svalues[[i]])){
          df_Svalues[[i]]$mav200[j] <- mean(df_Svalues[[i]]$adjusted[(j-200):(j-1)])
        }
      }
      str(df_Svalues[[1]])

      print(warnings())
```

Here is the error:
[image]

[image]

Thank you for any help, Bill.

Comment: You’re trying to take the mean of something which isn’t numeric or logical - so probably an NA value or character. Step through your code line by line, looking at the input for the function call giving the error, and you’ll find what’s causing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.  The `roll_mean()` function will be much faster than the loops.

```r
library(quantmod)
library(BatchGetSymbols)
library(TTR)
library(shiny)
library(lubridate)
library(neuralnet) # Neural net library

#import the first 20 stocks
df_SP500 <- GetSP500Stocks()

tickers <- head(df_SP500$Tickers,20)

#set date
my_date <- Sys.Date()
first.date <- my_date %m-% years(20)
last.date <- Sys.Date()

#pull data from tickers
stockValues <- list()

for (i in 1:length(tickers)){
  stockValues[[i]] <- getSymbols(tickers[i],auto.assign = FALSE, from = first.date)
}

#set up list for values
df_Svalues <- list()
for (i in 1:length(tickers)){
  # df_Svalues[[i]] <- stockValues[[i]][,paste0(tickers[i], ".Adjusted")]
  df_Svalues[[i]] <- stockValues[[i]][,6]
  df_Svalues[[i]]$mav10 <- 0
  df_Svalues[[i]]$mav50 <- 0
  df_Svalues[[i]]$mav200 <- 0
}
head(df_Svalues[[1]])
#>            MMM.Adjusted mav10 mav50 mav200
#> 2002-05-09     37.62978     0     0      0
#> 2002-05-10     37.80853     0     0      0
#> 2002-05-13     38.28524     0     0      0
#> 2002-05-14     38.72915     0     0      0
#> 2002-05-15     38.58318     0     0      0
#> 2002-05-16     38.55637     0     0      0
library(RcppRoll)
for (i in 1:length(tickers)){
  df_Svalues[[i]]$mav10[11:nrow(df_Svalues[[i]])] <- roll_mean(lag(as.numeric(df_Svalues[[i]][,1])), n=10, align="right")[-1]
  df_Svalues[[i]]$mav50[51:nrow(df_Svalues[[i]])] <- roll_mean(lag(as.numeric(df_Svalues[[i]][,1])), n=50, align="right")[-1]
  df_Svalues[[i]]$mav200[201:nrow(df_Svalues[[i]])] <- roll_mean(lag(as.numeric(df_Svalues[[i]][,1])), n=200, align="right")[-1]
}
  
head(df_Svalues[[1]], n=15)
#>            MMM.Adjusted    mav10 mav50 mav200
#> 2002-05-09     37.62978  0.00000     0      0
#> 2002-05-10     37.80853  0.00000     0      0
#> 2002-05-13     38.28524  0.00000     0      0
#> 2002-05-14     38.72915  0.00000     0      0
#> 2002-05-15     38.58318  0.00000     0      0
#> 2002-05-16     38.55637  0.00000     0      0
#> 2002-05-17     38.75300  0.00000     0      0
#> 2002-05-20     38.20777  0.00000     0      0
#> 2002-05-21     37.83237  0.00000     0      0
#> 2002-05-22     38.18566  0.00000     0      0
#> 2002-05-23     38.47009 38.25710     0      0
#> 2002-05-24     38.30843 38.34113     0      0
#> 2002-05-28     37.95811 38.39112     0      0
#> 2002-05-29     37.42518 38.35841     0      0
#> 2002-05-30     37.45511 38.22801     0      0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The `roll_mean()` function starts at time *t* and counts backward, so for a 10-period moving average it would start at the 10th value and choose values 10 all the way back to 1 to make the average.  Since it seems that you want the previous 10 periods, not including the current period, I had it calculating the rolling mean on the lag of the variable which should do the right thing.

Just so you can see, here's your original code fixed so the loops work:

```r
for (i in 1:length(tickers)){
  # Moving Average - 10
  for (j in 11:nrow(df_Svalues[[i]])){
    df_Svalues[[i]]$mav10[j] <- mean(df_Svalues[[i]][(j-10):(j-1),1])
  }
  # Moving Average - 50
  for (j in 51: nrow(df_Svalues[[i]])) {
    df_Svalues[[i]]$mav50[j] <- mean(df_Svalues[[i]][(j-50):(j-1),1])
  }
  # Moving Average - 200
  for (j in 201:nrow(df_Svalues[[i]])){
    df_Svalues[[i]]$mav200[j] <- mean(df_Svalues[[i]][(j-200):(j-1),1])
  }
}
```